# How can I install snap on rhel 8?

Tags: rhel8, snap

I am trying to install snap on my rhel 8.4 machine and it throws the following error

```
Error: 
 Problem: package snapd-2.54.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires snapd-selinux = 2.54.1-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides selinux-policy-base >= 3.14.3-80.el8_5.2 needed by snapd-selinux-2.54.1-1.el8.noarch
```

I have selinux-policy-3.14.3-67.el8_4.2 on my machine.

Comment: Try to post your question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)